# Is it possible to capture SSH+sudo output locally without writing the hostname and [sudo] lines?

Tags: ssh, sudo

Is it possible, when locally writing output from SSH command execution, to suppress the hostname and [sudo] lines?

For instance, when I SSH into a server and run `sudo <command>` it displays

```
<hostname>
[sudo] password for user:
```

This is written to the file I'm writing the output to. I'm using `sudo <command> 2>&1 /dev/null` but it isn't eliminating those lines.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo <command> 2>&1 /dev/null` won't redirect anything to `/dev/null`. Instead, you are:

- Calling `sudo` with 2 parameters: `<command>` and `/dev/null`. The second one will be passed to `<command>` when it gets executed.
- Redirecting error messages to standard output.

Here's a simple try:

```
$ sudo ls 2>&1 /dev/null
/dev/null
```

See: you get the result of `ls /dev/null`. However, you could do something like...

```
$ sudo ls >ls_output.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Which would:

- Call `sudo` with 1 parameter: `ls`.
- Redirect standard output to `ls_output.txt`.
- Redirect standard error to `/dev/null`.

With the above command, `ls_output.txt` would list the contents of the current working directory, and won't have any `stderr` data in it.